# Linked list c++: append function does not seem to work

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am trying to understand pointers and linked lists in c++. for this i have written a small Programm. I seem to have trouble going through the list with a curPtr which seems to give me all initial elements in the list but not the one i have appended. I have no clue what is the problem.
here is my main function:

```
int sizeOfLL = 5;
int* LLtail;
int* LLcur;
int* LLhead;
std::cout << "start values: " << (long long) LLhead << " " << (long long) LLcur  << " " <<  (long long) LLtail  << std::endl;
makeLListCstyle(LLhead, LLtail, sizeOfLL);
std::cout << "head in main(): " << (long long) LLhead << std::endl;
LLcur = LLhead;
std::cout << "cur in main(): " << (long long) LLcur <<  std::endl;
std::cout <<  "tail in main(): " << (long long) LLtail <<  std::endl;

for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfLL; i++){
    LLcur[i] = 3*i;

}

//LLcur[3]=3;

appendElement(LLtail, 2);
std::cout <<  "tail in main(): " << (long long) LLtail << " value: " << LLtail[0] <<  std::endl;
sizeOfLL = getElementsInList(LLhead, LLtail);
std::cout << sizeOfLL << endl;


for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfLL; i++){
    cout << "cur in main(): " << (long long) &LLcur[i] << " value: " << LLcur[i] << endl;

}

return 0;
```

here my llist.hpp

```
void makeLListCstyle(int* &head, int* &tail, int numElements){

    head = (int*) malloc(numElements * sizeof(int));
   // std::cout << "sizeof(int): " << sizeof(int) << endl;
   // std::cout << "head in makeLList(): " <<  (long long) head <<  std::endl;

    tail = head + numElements; // points now at address which is sizeif(int) * numElements further in memory.

   // std::cout <<  "tail in makeLList(): " << (long long) tail <<  std::endl;
   // return head;
}

void appendElement(int* &tail,  int newElement){

    std::cout <<  "tail in appendElement(): " << (long long) tail <<  std::endl;
   tail = tail+1;
    std::cout <<  "tail in appendElement(): " << (long long) tail <<  std::endl;
   // std::cout <<  "value of tail in appendElement(): " << (long long) *tail <<  std::endl;
    *tail = newElement;
   // std::cout <<  "value of tail in appendElement(): " << (long long) *tail <<  std::endl;
}

int getElementsInList(int* &head, int* &tail){
/*
    std::cout <<  "head in getElementsInList(): " << (long long) head <<  std::endl;
    std::cout <<  "tail in getElementsInList(): " << (long long) tail <<  std::endl;
    std::cout << ( (long long)(tail) - (long long)(head) )/ sizeof(int) << endl;
*/
    return ( (long long)(tail) - (long long)(head) ) / sizeof(int);

}
```

And here the output.

```
cur in main(): 18857008 value: 0
cur in main(): 18857012 value: 3
cur in main(): 18857016 value: 6
cur in main(): 18857020 value: 9
cur in main(): 18857024 value: 12
cur in main(): 18857028 value: 0
```

the last one should be a 2 not a zero. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Just as a note, try keeping your code width down to a reasonable size. It gets hard to read after a while.

Comment: This is not what we call a "linked list". More like an array wrapper.

Comment: In makeLListCStyle, it you should set tail=head not head+numElements

Comment: You use `[n]` to de-reference the list objects like array members. How did you allocate the list objects so that you can think, an index is allowed access anything?

Comment: Nothing in your program resembles something that was in the same room with a linked list once. Consider getting a C++ book and a general data structure book.

Comment: While it's possible to implement linked lists inside arrays, this is not the way you do it.

Comment: Okay, I guess it is not a linked list. I just wanted to understand pointers and dynamic memory. I thought this would be somewhat to a linked list. Obviously, i got more to learn. However, it is not clear to me why i should make head=tail. The tail should point to the last element, no? (okay, i seemingly point one too far)

Comment: @harper : My understanding is that A [0] is equivalent to *A for an array or dynamically allocated memory. So A[n] should be the same as *A+n, therefore I thought i can use [n] to access 'elements' or rather defined addresses of memory ( which were defined in by my malloc call). Is that wrong?

Comment: *A+n should be *(A+n) in my comment above

Comment: I recommend you to get a book about C programming and to read about data structurrs like a list. Your approach to implement data structures with links to each others on the base of an array leads you into problems and misunderstandings. A list becomes interesting when dynamically allocate and release items. That's impossible with the array.

Answer (score 0):

In your `makeLListCstyle` function you do

```
tail = head + numElements;
```

That makes `tail` point to *one beyond* the allocated memory.

So in `appendElement` when you do

```
tail = tail+1;
```

you're making `tail` point to *one more* element beyond the end of your allocated memory, leading to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) when you then write to this location.

---

Your code is basically equivalent to

```
int LLHead[5];
// Initialize elements 0 to 4
LLHead[6] = 2;
```

What you have is nowhere *close* to a linked list. All you have is a dynamically allocated array which you go out of bounds of.

Comment: this was my first intention but I thought then I thought this:`1st element from address 008 to 012,
2nd element from address 012 to 016,
3rd element from address 016 to 020,
4th element from address 020 to 024,
5th element from address 024 to 028`
I am just using the last 3 digits of the printed addresses which were like 18857028 in dec.